# Horizontal image picker vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to display a horizontal combo box in Vaadin. Is it possible to do that? 
If no, what is the best component to put in a custom component to accomplish this task? Like a Button that I change CSS for onClick or a Resource using another listener to highlight.

Comment: Horizontal image picker or combobox? what should this component do?

Comment: @d2k2: The component is a horizontal image picker, allowing user to select only one image. I'm looking for a component that can be "selected" like a table cell or something.

Comment: a very simple way would be to use a HorizontalLayout where you put the images in. Then you have to decide how you scroll trough the images. either by a scroll bar or with a "forward" and "backward" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that just by composing components: a `HorizontalVertical` or a `VerticalLayout` as the root layout, `Image` components to display the images and then add a `LayoutClickListener` to the layout to get the selected/clicked image. To highlight a selected `Image` you can add a style name for that in your `LayoutClickListener`.

There are also addons available in Vaadin Directory, which might be suitable for your needs:

- [ImageStrip](http://vaadin.com/addon/imagestrip)
- [ImageViewer](http://vaadin.com/addon/imageviewer)
- [Carousel](http://vaadin.com/addon/carousel)